# handle radio button behavior in multiple for loop

Tags: angular, for-loop, radio-button

I am having trouble in controlling the behavior of multiple radio select in multiple for loop.

**demo**
In below demo, when I check radio of 1st block it is selecting the same radio in 2nd block too. Please have a look. Actually I need to select different radio option in different blocks.

```
  visit: http://plnkr.co/edit/YpQZyv55tKxTGwDEi5gS?p=preview
```

Comment: sorry couldnt add demo while editing it 

http://plnkr.co/edit/YpQZyv55tKxTGwDEi5gS?p=preview

Comment: do you really want to have the same options for every radio button group?

Comment: no, actually I need different